# WCF-Service deciding between SOAP or RESTful services

Tags: wcf, rest, soap

What will be the correct point of decision to develop Web Service based on SOAP and RESTful services?

Comment: Hard to tell without any context ...

Comment: I'm trying to understand the main difference. 
I saw similar post some minutes ago and it make's sense. 
[Are REST and SOAP enemies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843330/are-rest-and-soap-enemies?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on your consumers and the technology they have available to them.  For example, a Ruby-on-Rails app that consumes your service is probably going to prefer REST, where a java client would probably prefer SOAP.

Comment: Thank you. I also saw some other comments in other thread that will also need to look at.
[Are REST and SOAP enemies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843330/are-rest-and-soap-enemies?rq=1)

Comment: No, (well some people will say yes) they're just different technologies for different uses.