# cURL on Apache showing .. "Access forbidden! Error 403"

Tags: php, apache, curl

I am testing simple API with cURL. It is, **calling from (a php file of) one Apache Server to (a php file of) another Apache Server**. It is ok testing locally. But when i test with my network PCs, it showing following 403 error:

`Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403`

Codes for Caller Server (Server 1) are:

```
function apicall($request_url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $return;
}
$request_url = 'http://192.168.1.205/api.php?cname=David';
$response = apicall($request_url);
```

Codes for Answering Server (Server 2) are:

```
echo "Hello ".$_GET['cname'];
```

cURL is enabled on both Apache. So why? What do i need to do?

Comment: Is `Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.` not a clear message? Is it your own server that you are querying or a 3rd party one?

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with cURL, it is your Apache configuration that is the problem.

Apache is configured in such a way the the resource at `api.php` is not available to the machine on which your script is running.

In you Apache configuration, for the root directory, you need to inspect these directives:

```
# Yours will not look like this
# The key point is look at the 'Order' and 'Allow'/'Deny' directives for the root directory
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Have a look at [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) and the sections immediately below it.

Alternatively, you may have some code somewhere in `api.php` that looks something like this:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
exit("Access forbidden!\nYou don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.\nIf you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.\nError 403");
```

...however, based on what you say is in your code, I think this is about the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAMP, make sure you **"put online"** the server.

Secondly,

Is you htaccess blocking it ?