# How to have a listener PhP script respond to GET requests

Tags: php, curl, remote-access

I'm trying to accomplish remote php call and return as described in this question: [PHP: Remote Function Call and returning the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460577/php-remote-function-call-and-returning-the-result)

However, I don't know how to make the listener script that responds to the GET request. How do I create the script, allow it to be called remotely, and have it process the request appropriately? Is there an example somewhere?

I understand this is probably a very low-level question, but I'm very new to PhP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to implement a listener, the web server is doing that for you. Just create a script and put it in your web directory. When the web server receives a GET request to that script, it will execute the PHP script.

In the script, you can just echo the values that you want to send back in a format that your calling function understands. (Of course you could also set some headers, if you feel that this is necessary).

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to code it. My main exposure to php has been looking through Wordpress code to fix formatting issues. Is there a simple example file I can retrofit?

Comment: Why didn´t you help him with some code? This is not an answer.

Comment: @debeka Because the whole point was that there's no need to implement anything to get the script called: it's all done by the web server. And the implementation of the RPC-related stuff is answered in the linked question. (BTW it seems to have helped the OP, since he accepted the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your listener PHP script responding to a remote call should be just like a script responding to a web browser's request. Use $_GET to get the input data.