# Google Scripts + Google API PHP

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps, google-api-php-client

I am trying to call one of my Google Scripts from my google-api-php-client and I can't find how to do this.

I deployed my app as a web app, and I got the web app url which I can call with curl, but I need to call it as my "google client".

I've found a list of apps inside my drive service, but I can't figure out how to find which app is the proper one and how to call it. I don't even know if it's the right thing to check first as I don't find anything from the documentation.

```
    $googleDrive = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->_googleClient);
    $test = $googleDrive->apps->listApps();
    var_dump($test);
```

And anyway if I get the app it just return an instance of Google_Service_Drive_App but there's nothing inside that to call the script with my post parameters.

**UPDATE:**

I am using the Google APIs Client Library for PHP

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation

The user is authenticated through oAuth with \Google_Client(); with all the DRIVE scopes for permission.

My Google Script is located inside the user drive, and I'm trying to execute it remotely. I deployed the script as a web app. Below you can find the Script File url.

https://script.google.com/macros/s/[my_google_script_id]/exec

Basically I want the Google APIs Client Library for PHP to execute the Script File from the user drive.

I tried to use the Google_Http_Request class directly and execute it with the Google_Client, it almost worked as expected.

```
    $googleRequest = new \Google_Http_Request($url, 'POST', null, array('post' => 'parameters'));
    $this->_googleClient->execute($googleRequest);
```

Comment: Are you trying to do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7460613) with your Google Apps Script as the 2nd server? You can't get a list of the functions inside a script through that API - see [resource representation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps). You should instead implement your Google Apps Script web service to use ContentService to provide the responses to your PHP posts.

Comment: I use the "doPost" function, I can execute the script with CURL without problem, but I need to run it "as the current google client", not as anonymous. Do I need to add something into my curl post request to let google know who exactly is running the script.

Comment: That sounds different than your question... maybe you need to edit the question to make it clearer what your SPECIFIC problem is. Have you seen [User authentication in PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/users/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using CURL request directly passing the "Authorization" header with the token_type and the access_token and it worked as expected. I didn't find any way to do this using the Google APIs Client Library for PHP

```
    POST
    Authorization: Bearer [your_auth_token]
    Content-Length: 0
```